# MySQL Query Help Please Join multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

i have these 4 tables
(see picture)

[image]

what i would like to do is this

UID | f_name | m_name | l_name | suffix | class | subject

000 |jan     |s       |gerry   | null   |test   | arts

001 |rey     |s       |ronald  |null    |test2  |123

but this query ive created gives me this output

```html
SELECT CONCAT(tbl_users.f_name, ' ', tbl_users.m_name, ' ', tbl_users.l_name, ' ', tbl_users.suffix) AS insName, tbl_classinstructor.UID, tbl_subject.subject, tbl_class.class FROM tbl_class, tbl_classinstructor LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_users.UID = tbl_classinstructor.UID, tbl_classsubject LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_subject ON tbl_classsubject.SID = tbl_subject.SID
```

UID | f_name | m_name | l_name | suffix | class | subject

000 |jan     |s       |gerry   | null   |test   | arts

000 |jan     |s       |gerry   | null   |test   | 123

001 |rey     |s       |ronald  |null    |test2  |arts

001 |rey     |s       |ronald  |null    |test2  |123

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `left join` properly. Here how it should be

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(tbl_users.f_name, ' ', tbl_users.m_name, ' ', tbl_users.l_name, ' ', tbl_users.suffix) AS insName, 
tbl_classinstructor.UID, 
tbl_subject.subject, 
tbl_class.class FROM tbl_class
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_classinstructor on tbl_classinstructor.CID = tbl_class.CID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_users.UID = tbl_classinstructor.UID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_classsubject on tbl_classsubject.CID = tbl_class.CID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_subject ON tbl_classsubject.SID = tbl_subject.SID
```